# SQL : how to perform calculations with unrelated tables?

Tags: sql, confluence

I have very basic understanding of SQL.

And I have tables in a confluence page with various data. I would like to create a template my team can use where they have to fill in those tables with some values and then some automatic calculation is performed with the SQL query using the table transformer module.

The structure would be something similar to :

**workload table**

```
+-------+-------+
| task  | hours |
+-------+-------+
| task1 |     2 |
| task2 |     5 |
+-------+-------+
```

**ratetable** (yes usually it will  be one person)

```
+--------+------+
| person | rate |
+--------+------+
| John   |  500 |
+--------+------+
```

**project table** (yes usually it will be a single project)

```
+----------+----------+
| project  | duration |
+----------+----------+
| project1 |       15 |
+----------+----------+
```

And what I would like to achieve is to be able to compute the sum of the tasks multiplied by the rate multiplied by the duration. Don't mind the units, I have put a simple example but on my side, units work.

Of course I can use constants and this would be way easier. But the way confluence works, I can't do it easily because I can't fetch constants from the template in the SQL query (or at least I did not succeed achieving that) and putting constant in the SQL code is not very user friendly for my colleagues and they would for sure forget to change the numbers from time to time.

Basically, if I could easily reduce a table in SQL to a constant I can use everywhere, this would achieve what I want I think but I don't know if this is feasible in SQL easily. Apparently, in confluence, I cannot use the `CREATTE FUNCTION` capabilities.

Comment: You need a projecttask table too.

Comment: As you describe it, seems to me that you want to get the result (2 * 500 + 5 * 500) = 3500 with independence of the project table and the people in ratetable table, is it that correct?

Comment: It's not exactly like that. I do some intermediate computations. Basically the tasks are function of the project's duration. So I do some intermediate computation with the project's duration. I end up with a cofficient X. With that coefficient, I can then multiply the tasks' hours. And then I end up with a workload for the person in days that I can multiply by its rate.

Mathematically, it's very very basic. It's just that I want to put that as a template in confluence with variables and the easiest way I found was through SQL.